# Combinatorial Prove

Tags: combinatorics

I'm been trying to figure it out but have no ideia, someone said me to start with Euler's formulas but do not know how to to it.

Here is the formula they told me to prove (i'm not sure if it is the way to solve the problem):
[C(n,0)]² + [C(n,1)]²+.... + [C(n,n]²=C(2n,n)

Here is the question:

A chess master plays during 11 weeks at least 1 game a day but no more than 12 games per week. Prove that exist a set of consecutive days in which he plays exactly 20 games.

Thanks for the help!

Comment: The formula you mentioned has been posted here several times.

Comment: The other part of the question is also essentially a duplicate.

Comment: See http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1869328/problem-related-to-series-of-binomial-coefficients/1869379#1869379